# android install new software in eclipse not working

Tags: android, sdk

i want to install android sdk to eclipse but the path name https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ and http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ not working for me im using windows7 .

I installed same  in another windows xp system it is working fine. pls solve this problem

or

can i move the installed sdk from XP system  to windows7 ? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your plugin dependencies. You might be using an older version of Eclipse which do not have support for recent Android application development. You can track missing dependencies by going to the Help menu and licking 'Install New software'. You should see error indicators if your Eclipse version doesn't have them.

Comment: Have you managed to fix this error? Please get back to me so we can confirm if it worked for you. This way we could help others having the same problem fix this error. Thanks.

Comment: In my case the new software were actually installed. but eclipse not displayd the avd manager window.At the same time  i could run avd on commandline. So no way out for me , Thats why i copied sdk folder and eclipse from my xp mashine to win7. it working fine now...